# How to find intersection between an array, and an array of arrays

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays:

```
 array1 = [:key1, :key2]
 array2 = [[:key1,2],[:key2,8],[:key3,1]]
```

I would like to have an array of arrays in `array2` whose `:key...` exists in `array1`. For example, for the above:

```
 result = [[:key1,2],[:key2,8]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This satisfies your example:

```
array2.select {|key,value| array1.include?(key) }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works using a quick hash slice:

```
array1.zip(Hash[array2].values_at(*array1))
=> [[:key1, 2], [:key2, 8]]
```

It won't work if the key values in `array2` ever repeat, because they'll stomp on the previous instances. Otherwise, if they don't repeat, this will be extremely fast, especially if `array2` grows.